# Find where f(x) changes in a list, with bisection (in Python)

Tags: python, bisection, git-bisect, bisect

Reasoning: I'm trying to implement, in Python, something similar to `git bisect`, but with basically a list of directories.

I have a (long) list of version numbers like this:
`['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4']`

I have a function `works()` which takes a version number, and returns a value.

`[works(x) for x in my_list]` would look like:
`['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']`
... but running `works()` is very expensive.

I would like to do some kind of bisect which will find the change boundary.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply use **binary search**:

```
def binary_f(f,list):
    frm = 0
    to = len(list)
    while frm < to:
        mid = (frm+to)>>1
        if f(list[mid]):
            to = mid
        else:
            frm = mid+1
    return frm
```

It will return the **first index `i`** for which `bool(f(list[i]))` is `True`.

Of course the function assumes that the the map of `f` on the `list` is of the form:

```
f(list) == [False,False,...,False,True,True,...,True]
```

If this is not the case, it will usually find a *swap* but which one is rather undefined.

Say `f` is simply "*the version is 2 or higher*" so `lambda v:v >= '2'`, then it will return:

```
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '2',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
2
```

So **index `2`**. In case the entire list would return with `False` objects, it will **return `len(list)`. Since it "assumes" the element just outside the list will be evaluated to `True`:

```
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '4.2',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
5
```

Of course in your example `f` is `works`.

Experiments:

```
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '2',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
2
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '0',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
0
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '1',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
0
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '1.13',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
1
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '2.4',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
3
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '3',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
3
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '3.2',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
4
>>> binary_f(lambda v:v >= '4.2',['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4'])
5
```

(I here of course did a very cheap version check, but it works of course for more sophisticated predicates).

Since this is binary search, it will run in *O(log n)* with *n* the number of items in the list whereas linear search *can* result in *O(n)* checks (which is usually more expensive).

**EDIT**: in case the list contains two values and you want to find the *swap*, you can simply first compute the value for index `0`:

```
val0 = f(list[0])
```

and then provide `binary_f`:

```
binary_f(lambda v:works(v) != val0,list)
```

Or putting it into a nice function:

```
def binary_f_val(f,list):
    val0 = f(list[0])
    return binary_f(lambda x:f(x) != val0,list)
```

Comment: Isn't this overkill?  list.index() does the same thing, does it not?

Comment: it does but with `O(n)` speed, so with big lists it's much slower.

Comment: @rshield: If you read the question carefully, you see that **`works`** is an expensive operation. It could mean you run an entire testbanch against it. Now imagine there are hundreds of versions you have to check. In that case, this algorithm will perform 7-8 checks, whereas next will on average check 50 cases. If each testbench takes an hour. I would be glad to only need to wait 8 hours instead of half a week.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I stand corrected.  I see why binary is the best solution here.

Comment: This is great, but I actually misstated the problem a little bit, I just realized. See update.

Comment: @dmd: that does not change much: you can simply use `lambda x : works(x) == 'bar'` as function.

Comment: oh, I see now how  I can do this - I should just feed works() neighboring pairs, thus reducing the problem to false/true.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but I don't actually know what foo and bar are. but my prev comment stands.

Comment: @dmd: yeah indeed. As long as you somehow can convert it into a predictate (and the predicate swaps once from `False` to `True` it works).

Comment: @dmd: you can simply first inspect the borders of the list: look what `val = works(list[0])` is and then feed it like `lambda x:works(x) != val`.

Comment: I think there is a module that can do the binary search for you

Comment: use `bisect` to do that for you. But there's a little catch: a version list like `['1.0', '1.14', '2.3', '3.1', '4', "11.4"]` _appears_ sorted, but insertion fails because numerical sort isn't version sort. For instance `10.1` is inserted in second position...

Comment: I wonder if you could reuse the Python [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module for this.  You'd probably have to define a custom class with a `__getitem__` that calls `works()` lazily.

Comment: @MariusGedminas: you can indeed construct something as a `maplist` that is a "virtual list" and lazily calls the mapping function. If I find some time after hours I will try to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to implement binary search algorithm ... this is pretty straight forward,  the rough draft of algorithm is below.  I haven't tested it,  but you should get the idea and take care of edge cases when your version list of length 1 or 2:

```
def whereWorks(versions, works):

   middle = len(versions)/2

   good = works(versions[middle])

   if middle < 2:
       return good ? 0 : 1

   if works(middle):
         return whereWorks(versions[0:middle])
   else
         return whereWorks(versions[middle:])+middle
```

Answer (score -1):

That is what `next()` is for.

```
result = next(x for x in my_list if works(x))
```

A faster way but a more complicated one would be:

```
alist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

def check(my_list, tracking=0):

    def criterion(i):
        return bool(i)

    if len(my_list) == 1:
        if my_list[0] == 1:
            return tracking
        else:
            return tracking + 1

    start = len(my_list) // 2

    if criterion(my_list[start]):
        return check(my_list[:start], tracking=tracking)
    else:
        tracking += start + 1
        return check(my_list[start+1:], tracking=tracking)

print(check(alist))  # returns 6
```

Which is a bisection method. Cuts the list recursively in half, checks the element in the middle and moves the the slice on the left if it is 1 or on the right if it is a 0. The `tracking` tracks the index. I would love to have a `timeit` by someone if he\she has the time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is still not binary but operates at log(n)